# how to avoid expiring access token facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I know there are more questions similar to this but the more I read the more confused I get.

http://www.palloskar.is/blog/?tezt

I'm getting his posts via the api ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=24873774107%2Fposts )

That's all nice and fine but the access token expires, I'm not using the PHP SDK.

How can I make this work in the long term and why do I even need access tokens to something that is public? https://www.facebook.com/24873774107

Do I need to make an app that has this token, or do I need to make a long term token.. or do I need the artist to make a token? Or do I need to use SDK?

Whatever the answer is I think it's a bit silly for getting PUBLIC posts, but if someone can advise me in the simplest way to do this. I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You noticed right, for public information you don't need an access token. As soon as you're trying to access fields, you need an access token.

Facebook can be a bit confusing when in comes to permissions but let me explain this a little bit.

There are four kinds of tokens all in all, I go in depth with two of them.

**User access token**

When you're trying to perform actions on a users behalf, you need to make sure the user permitted access in order to be able to perform this action. For example reading a users feed, posting a comment on the users behalf, etc.

These tokens expire pretty quickly and you need to renew them, or request an user access token that lives longer (long-living access token).

Since that is not what you're trying to do you don't need an user access token. You are trying to read the feed of a page.

**App Access Token**

That kind of token is normally used when you're performing actions on behalf of your app. So said: the user is not related to an action that is performad via an app access token (e.g. reading comments of a public page, etc).

The special thing about an app access token is, that **it does not expire**. It lasts forever so you can be sure that actions that are performed using your app access token, do not need further mechanisms to check for expiration.

So when you need to obtain public information use your app access token.
It's true that you have to create an app in order to be able to use an app access token.

In order to obtain your token, you can either query the graph:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials

(see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/)

Or use the API Explorer. See the picture below.

[image: Access Token]

As soon as you've obtained your access token you can make the request you wish. I take your example:

https://graph.facebook.com/24873774107/posts?access_token=417941515002115|qxJFxIU0vMKTPZZrvhJmIcix-7c

As you can see I queried the graph and passed my app access token with it. Now I don't get an oauth exception but the data I wanted to have.

---

I know facebook authentication is a bit of an hard topic, but once you understood it, it's a piece of cake.

Give it a read: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Happy coding!